# Campos mutables en Dataclasses, evitar que sean compartidos por todas las instancias

Tags: python, python-3.x, diseño-de-clases

Como práctica, diseño una base de datos con dos tipos de objetos. Cada uno de ellos tiene varios campos, y algunos de ellos son instancias de clases que he creado para el uso. Al ir añadiendo objetos a la base de datos me doy cuenta de que estos campos, en lugar de ser individuales para cada instancia, se comparten.

Concretamente este campo es una instancia de una clase `Historial` que acumula notas y algunos cambios. Pero todos las instancias del mismo tipo (`ObjVs`) comparten las mismas notas... Me está costando encontrar y entender el problema.

Lo siguiente es una versión reducida del programa que incluye las clases implicadas.

```
class ObjNota:
    '''Objeto básico que contiene una nota.'''
    def __init__(self, text:str, tag:str):
        self.nota={"text":text, "tag":tag, "fecha":time.asctime()}


class ObjNotas:
    '''Objeto de control para las notas.'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.notas=[]

    # Omito métodos que gestionan las notas.

class ObjHistorial(ObjNotas):
    '''Objeto que gestiona la antiguedad, las notas y las vacaciones.'''
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() #self.notas = []
        self.antiguedad = None


@dataclass
class ObjVs:
    ''' objeto operarios '''
    nombre:str
    id:int = None           # Nº identificación de empresa
    telf:str = None
    movilidad:str = None    # Fijo en servicio, correturnos o sin servicio.
    tip:int = None          # Nº tarjeta interprofesional
    servicio_asignado:str = None
    historial:ObjHistorial = ObjHistorial()
```

La idea es ir añadiendo los operarios a la base de datos, con la mayor parte de sus campos vacíos, e ir editándolos posteriormente. Por lo que me interesa que los historiales sean objetos inicializados pero sin datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente si creamos dos objetos podemos ver fácilmente a que te refieres:

```
>>> a = ObjVs("Pepe")    
>>> b = ObjVs("Maria")  

>>> id(a.historial.notas)
139639690892168
>>> id(b.historial.notas)
139639690892168

>>> a.historial.notas.append("Hola")
>>> a.historial.notas
['Hola']
>>> b.historial.notas
['Hola']
```

Pero no es `ObjVs.historial.notas` el problema, el problema es `ObjVs.historial`, instancia de `ObjHistorial`:

```
>>> id(a.historial)
139639701356160
>>> id(b.historial)
139639701356160
```

Este problema se debe a que has caído inadvertidamente en uno de los "anti-patrones" más comunes en Python, **usar objetos mutables como argumentos por defecto**.

Hay que tener en cuenta que **Python almacena los valores por defecto de las variables miembro como atributos de clase**, lo cual hace que la práctica anterior cause que todas las instancias de `ObjVs` usan la misma instancia de `ObjHistorial`. Ten en cuenta que el `__init__` equivalente a tu dataclass sería algo así:

```
class ObjVs:

    def __init__(self,
                 nombre: str,
                 id: Optional[int] = None,
                 movilidad: Optional[str] = None,
                 telf: Optional[int] = None,
                 servicio_asignado: Optional[str] = None,
                 historial: ObjHistorial = ObjHistorial()) -> None:

        self.nombre  = nombre
        self.id = id 
        self.telf = telf
        self.movilidad = movilidad
        self.telf = telf 
        self.servicio_asignado = servicio_asignado
        self.historial = historial
```

Es muy diferente a hacer en el `__init__`:

```
self.historial = ObjHistorial()
```

o a una implementación correcta de un parámetro por defecto mutable en una función o método:

```
from typing import Optional

class ObjVs:
    def __init__(self, historial: Optional[ObjHistorial] = None) -> None:
        self.historial = ObjHistorial() if historial is None else historial
```

en cuyo caso si que tendrías una instancia de `ObjHistorial` por cada instancia de `OBjVs`.

Existe una forma de manejar los objetos mutables como argumentos por defecto en las dataclass mediante el uso de [`field`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field), el cual permite personalizar cada campo de una dataclass individualmente. Admite los siguientes parámetros:

- **`default`:** valor predeterminado del campo.
- **`default_factory`:** *callable* sin argumentos (podemos usar `functools.partial` de ser necesario) que devuelve el valor inicial del campo. No se debe usar nunca junto a `default`. Aún cuando `init` está definido como `False` el campo será pasado al `__init__` porque es la única forma de asignar un valor inicial.
- **`init`**: habilitar el uso del campo en el método `__ init __ ()` (El valor predeterminado es `True`).
- **`repr`**: habilitar el uso del campo en la generación de la cadena por parte del método `__repr__` (El valor predeterminado es `True`).
- **`compare`**: incluir el campo en los  métodos encargados de implementar las comparaciones y los test de igualdad para los objetos, como `__eq__` (El valor predeterminado es `True`).
- **`hash`**: incluir el campo al calcular `hash()`. (Por defecto usa el mismo valor que `compare`).
- **`metadata`**: mapping (o `None`) con información sobre el campo.

a nosotros nos interesa el parámetro  `default_factory`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional


class ObjNota:
    '''Objeto básico que contiene una nota.'''
    def __init__(self, text: str, tag: str):
        self.nota={"text":text, "tag":tag, "fecha":time.asctime()}


class ObjNotas:
    '''Objeto de control para las notas.'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.notas = []

    # Omito métodos que gestionan las notas.

class ObjHistorial(ObjNotas):
    '''Objeto que gestiona la antiguedad, las notas y las vacaciones.'''
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() #self.notas = []
        self.antiguedad = None


@dataclass
class ObjVs:
    ''' objeto operarios '''
    nombre: str
    id_: Optional[int] = None           # Nº identificación de empresa
    telf: Optional[str] = None
    movilidad: Optional[str] = None     # Fijo en servicio, correturnos o sin servicio.
    tip: Optional[int] = None           # Nº tarjeta interprofesional
    servicio_asignado: Optional[str] = None
    historial: ObjHistorial = field(default_factory=ObjHistorial)
```

Ahora todo funciona como debería:

```
>> id(a.historial)
139892733289248
>>> id(b.historial)
139892733289360

>>> a.historial.notas.append("Hola")
>>> a.historial.notas
['Hola']
>>> b.historial.notas
[]
```

Esto permite pasar una instancia de `ObjHistorial` o `None` al instanciar `ObjVs` (`a = ObjVs("Juan", historial=ObjHistorial()`)). Si no quieres que sea un parámetro , puedes usar el método `__post_init__` el cual es ejecutado inmediatamente después del `__init__`:

```
@dataclass
class ObjVs:
    ''' objeto operarios '''
    nombre: str
    id_: Optional[int] = None           # Nº identificación de empresa
    telf: Optional[str] = None
    movilidad: Optional[str] = None     # Fijo en servicio, correturnos o sin servicio.
    tip: Optional[int] = None           # Nº tarjeta interprofesional
    servicio_asignado: Optional[str] = None

    def  __post_init__(self):
        self.historial: ObjHistorial = ObjHistorial()
```

> **Nota:** he modificado los tipos en la dataclass para que sea conforme con MyPy, el resto lo he dejado igual porque me falta información para asignar los tipos adecuadamente.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta Jose, muy útil como siempre... Al final para el caso sobre el que había preguntado, con  `historial: ObjHistorial = field(default_factory=ObjHistorial)` lo he solucionado perfectamente.

Ahora... Lo había omitido en la pregunta, pero `ObjVs` también tiene un campo `direccion` que es un objeto muy simple con algunos atributos. A diferencia de `Objhistorial`, a veces me interesa que se inicialice 'vacío' cuando instancio `ObjVs` y otras veces con una cadena como argumento... pero `default_factory` no me lo permite. Al final he recurrido a solucionarlo en `_post_init_` para que se adapte según el caso y funciona bien, aunque tal vez haya alguna forma mejor de hacerlo.

```
class ObjDireccion:
    def __init__(self, direccion=None):
        self.dir = direccion
        self.coordenadas = None

@dataclass
class ObjVs:
    nombre:str
    direccion:ObjDireccion = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.direccion:
            self.direccion = ObjDireccion(self.direccion)
        else:
            self.direccion = ObjDireccion()


v1 = ObjVs(nombre = 'Pedro', direccion='Barcelona')
v2 = ObjVs(nombre = 'Maria')
print (id(v1.direccion), v1.direccion.dir)
print (id(v2.direccion), v2.direccion.dir)

# 7281072 Barcelona
# 7280720 None
```